# Javascript Loop Structure necessary test multiple conditionals and push an array of custom objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have a bit of a logic problem with my code here, and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Constraints:

1. Each item pushed will be an event, grouped by "name" and displayed inline in a chart.
2. EPC, M1, or M2 may have the value of null.
3. An event should be created with a 'start' of first non-null timeline and 'end' of the next non-null timeline value. (no need to check beyond m2 since none will contain null value). There should be at least 4 milestones in every group.
4. Should continue until no more 'groups' exist (content[i].name).

Currently, my code has a couple of issues:

1. Only creates one event per group.
2. EPC not accounted for in iteration, and unhandled if start and non-null.

Here is the code:

```
getMileStone = function(obj) {
    if(!obj) { return };
        propCounter = 1;
        newcount = 0;
        for(propCounter = 1; propCounter <= 7; propCounter++) {
            if(obj.timeline["m" + propCounter]) {
                data[newcount] = {key: "m" + propCounter, value: obj.timeline["m" + propCounter]};
                return data[newcount];
                newcount++;
            }
         }

        };

        getSecondStone = function(obj) {

            switch(getMileStone(current).key){

                case 'm1': return {value: obj.timeline['m2']};
                break;
                case 'm2': return {value: obj.timeline['m3']};
                break;
                case 'm3': return {value: obj.timeline['m4']};
                break;
                case 'm4': return {value: obj.timeline['m5']};
                break;
                case 'm5': return {value: obj.timeline['m6']};
                break;
                case 'm6': return {value: obj.timeline['m7']};
                break;
                default: return {value: obj.timeline['m1']};
            }

        };

for(i=0;i< content.length;i++) {
 current = content[i];
 firstMileStone = getMileStone(current); 
 secondMileStone = getSecondStone(current);
  result.push({
  'start': new Date(current.epc || firstMileStone.value),
  'end': new Date(current.m1 || secondMileStone.value),
  'content': firstMileStone.key,
  'group' : current.name,
  'className' : firstMileStone.key
 });
}
```

And here is the array content being read:

```
content = [{
"name": "5-HP-N/A-N/A-F8",
"node": {
    "name": "5",
    "id": 14
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": null,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1554087600000,
    "m4": 1593572400000,
    "m5": 1625108400000,
    "m6": 1641006000000,
    "m7": 1656644400000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F8",
    "id": 1
  }
},
{
  "name": "7-HP-N/A-N/A-F8",
  "node": {
    "name": "7",
    "id": 15
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": null,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1491015600000,
    "m4": 1530414000000,
    "m5": 1561950000000,
    "m6": 1577847600000,
    "m7": 1593572400000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F8",
    "id": 1
  }
},
{
"name": "5-XM-N/A-PLT-F8",
"node": {
    "name": "5",
    "id": 14
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": null,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1554087600000,
    "m4": 1593572400000,
    "m5": 1625108400000,
    "m6": 1641006000000,
    "m7": 1656644400000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F8",
    "id": 1
  }
},
{
"name": "40-LP-TFS-FSL-F7",
"node": {
    "name": "40",
    "id": 4
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": 1349060400000,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1262314800000,
    "m4": 1301626800000,
    "m5": 1333249200000,
    "m6": 1341111600000,
    "m7": 1357009200000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F7",
    "id": 3
  }
},
{
"name": "40-LP-SST-TI-F7",
"node": {
    "name": "40",
    "id": 4
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": 1349060400000,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1262314800000,
    "m4": 1301626800000,
    "m5": 1333249200000,
    "m6": 1341111600000,
    "m7": 1357009200000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F7",
    "id": 3
  }
},
{
"name": "28-LPQ-TN3-QCOM-F1",
"node": {
    "name": "28",
    "id": 2
},
"timeline": {
    "epc": 1349060400000,
    "m1": null,
    "m2": null,
    "m3": 1285902000000,
    "m4": 1325386800000,
    "m5": 1357009200000,
    "m6": 1372647600000,
    "m7": 1388545200000
},
"fab": {
    "name": "F1",
    "id": 2
}
}];
```

Currently, all events created also begin with m3. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Please use local variables, declared with `var`. Please don't use unintroduced variables like `data`.

Comment: Your second `return` statement in `getMilestone` seems wrong, and please get rid of the annoying repetitions in `getSecondStone`.

Comment: possible duplicate of previous question [Converting JSON data array to different structure with conditionals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13905498/converting-json-data-array-to-different-structure-with-conditionals)

Answer (score 0):

I left a comment on your previous question. Here is the implementation of my comment.

```
// get all non-null milestones
getMileStone = function (obj) {
    var result = [];

    for (var o in obj.timeline) {
        if (obj.timeline[o]) {
            result.push({ key: o, value: obj.timeline[o] });
        }
    }
    //dummy value for end pairing
    result.push({key: 'end', value : null});
    return result;
};


// loop over content array (seems like you have an array of objects)
for (var i = 0; i < content.length; i++) {
    current = content[i];
    var milestones = getMileStone(current);

    //loop through the non-null milestones
    for (var j = 0; j < milestones.length - 1; j++) {
        result.push({
            'group': current.name,
            'content': milestones[j].key,
            'start': new Date(milestones[j].value),
            'end': milestones[j + 1].value != null ? new Date(milestones[j + 1].value):null,
            'classname': milestones[j].value
        });
    }

}
```